# Can I get these template arguments deduced?

Tags: c++, templates

I left out the template parameters where the question marks were and I got an error, for obvious reason, but what to do in this case? I essentially want the two parameter arguments < ? , ? > to be the types of the getter and setter.

```
template <typename TGet, typename TSet>
class Object
{public:
    Object(int i, float f, TGet getter, TSet setter, const char* name) {}
};




class Creator
{public:
    template <typename T, typename ... TArgs>
    static T* create(int i, float f, TArgs ... args)
    {
        return new Object(i, f, args...);
    }

};

int main()
{
    Creator::create<Object< ? , ? >>(
        7,
        0.f,
        []() { return "Called Getter"; },
        [](const char* i) { std::cout << "Called Setter"; },
        "Name");
    
}
```

Also, I noted both my functions can become functions pointers, what if they were lambdas? What would go in the angled brackets < > ?

Comment: Did you stop going through your old questions to accept answers you've already gotten? It doesn't seem like you came very far in that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the compiler deduce the types for you:

```
template <typename ... TArgs> // removed 'typename T'
static auto create(int i, float f, TArgs ... args)
{ //   ^^^^
    return new Object(i, f, args...);
}
```

And

```
Creator::create(
    7,
    0.f,
    []() { return "Called Getter"; },
    [](const char* i) { std::cout << "Called Setter"; },
    "Name");
```

<kbd>[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/q774a5)</kbd>

Comment: Oh hangon, that example I posted wasn't the one that wasn't working on my program. oops. Maybe I should ask another question.

Comment: In my case the return new Object(i,f, args...); was return new T(i, f, args...);  When I rewrote it to a simpler example I made a mistake.